# keep getting "ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user' "

Tags: mysql

I'm logged in as root in MySQL database and I get the error below:

`ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'`

when I try to run the following command:

`mysql> select * from mysql.user\G`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

her's something that might be helpful:

1.

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+ 
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wordpress`.`wordpress` TO 'root'@'localhost'    |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```